# Spring MVC URIEncoding can't send requestparam correctly

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, uri, uriencoding

I need to send some request parameters from browser to Spring MVC controller and process them later like method parameters. The problem is that tomcat I guess didn't put right encoding for URI data which passing through. Instead of `'Имя'` I'm having: `%D0%9C%D0%91%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%A3+%D0%B4%2F%D1%81%E2%84%969%D1%81.+%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0`

I use to read about this type of problem which occurs because of tomcat does not have URI encoding preinstalled.

If you mind do I have body encoding in tomcat config web.xml, so Yes I have:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> 
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>tru?</param-value>
        </init-param>       
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

So I'm curious do I have to set up anything else to container config.? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the URIEncoding attribute for the HTTP connector in `server.xml` file inside your tomcat config dir:

```
<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" ...  />
```

Comment: Yes Sir. This is absolutely right. But I tried it before. The problem is that connector server.xml rewrite itself on each reboot of container. I tried to install autoDeploy="true" to false, but it is keep do same things againg.

Comment: What version of tomcat are you using in your setup? That's a really strange behaviour

Comment: Thank you Sir. It perfectly works. I don't know why, but when I install again my tomcat it just works fine

Answer (score 0):

Only certain way I found to do this without changing Tomcat configuration is:

put parameter in form

```html
<form onsubmit="encodeParameter(this.param)">
  <input type="text" name="param" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and then encode it before submitting to server

```js
function encodeParameter(param){
  param.value =encodeURIComponent(param.value);
}
```

now on server you will get correct string.